# Spring java config issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am using java config for spring security and I am trying to replace this code with no luck

```
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
```

cant find any info about how to use the position in java config 
Update i am trying to replace this code by java config but with no luck

```
 <security:http
        realm="Protected API"
        use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false"
        create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="PUT" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="DELETE" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
</security:http>

<bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.rest.UnauthorizedEntryPoint" />

<bean class="net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.rest.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
</bean>
```

and this is my AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
```

{

```
private final UserDetailsService userService;


public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(UserDetailsService userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);

    String authToken = this.extractAuthTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
    String userName = TokenUtils.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);

    if (userName != null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

        if (TokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}


private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request)
{
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
    }

    return (HttpServletRequest) request;
}


private String extractAuthTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
{
    /* Get token from header */
    String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");

    /* If token not found get it from request parameter */
    if (authToken == null) {
        authToken = httpRequest.getParameter("token");
    }

    return authToken;
}
```

Hope this is clearer

Comment: what you want to do actually? provide some detail information.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#filter-stack) are the filter classes in the order of execution and with the `addFilter` method of the `HttpSecurity` class you add your own filters:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilter(new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter());
  ...
```

You have to either extend or provide an instance of the defined Spring filters. The order is based on the class or superclass so you don't have to add the position:
[JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

Comment: Thanks! But do i need to replace it or add it before or after ?

Comment: Thanks your answer is clear and great! another problem i am having is where to inject the user service public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(UserDetailsService userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}

Comment: Put an `@Autowired` annotation before the constructor.

Comment: Thanks ! but i keep getting threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified